# A locally convex space is metrizable if and only if its topology is determined by a countable set of seminorms.

Tags: functional-analysis

A locally convex space is metrizable if and only if its topology is determined by a countable set of seminorms.

In the proof of Conway's book, I have a trouble in understanding => direction:

Assume that $X$ is metrizable with metric $\rho$. Let $U_n = \{x: \rho(x,0)<1/n \}$. Because $X$ is locally convex, there are continuous seminorms $q_1, \cdots, q_k$ and $\epsilon_1, \cdots, \epsilon_k>0$ such that $\cap_{j=1}^k \{x: q_j(x)<\epsilon_j \}\subset U_n$. Let $p_n := \epsilon_1^{-1} q_1 + \cdots + \epsilon_k^{-1} q_k$. Then it is proved that $x_j \to 0$ in $X$ if and only if for each $n$, $p_n(x_j) \to 0$ as $j \to \infty$. **This shows that $\{ p_n \}$ determines the topology on $X$.**

I can't understand the last sentence. Why does it hold?

My trial: $x_j \to 0$ in $(X,\rho)$ iff for each $n$, $p_n(x_j) \to 0$, and I  proved that this is equivalent to $x_j\to 0$ in $(X,\{ p_n \})$. Since translation is a homeomorphism, this means that $x_j \to x$ in $(X,\rho)$ iff  $x_j\to x$ in $(X,\{ p_n \})$. Now if $C$ is a closed set in $(X,\rho)$ and $x_j \in C$, $x_j \to x$ in $(X,\{ p_n \})$, then $x_j \to x$ in $(X,\rho)$, so $x \in C$. So $C$ is a closed set in $(X,\{ p_n \})$. By the symmetry, this means $(X,\rho)$=$(X,\{ p_n \})$.

Comment: If $V$ is a vector space and $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are two vector space topologies on $V$ such that convergence to $0$ in $\tau_1$ is equivalent to convergence in $\tau_2$, then $\tau_1=\tau_2$. Indeed, this means that the identity $(V,\tau_1)\leftrightarrow(V,\tau_2)$ is continuous in both directions at $0$, and being linear, it is continuous in both directions, hence a homeomorphism, which means that $\tau_1=\tau_2$.